# How can I easily render Box2D polygons with ShapeRenderer in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, jbox2d

In the `PolygonShape` object, there is the method `setAsBox()` which allows for creating rectangles easily, but there is no `getAsBox()` for cases where you know the polygon is a box. I know Box2D comes with it's own renderer, but I need to make custom renders.

Also, `PolygonShape` objects have a `getVertex()` method, but it has no return, and it takes a second argument of a `vector2`, for some reason. I don't know how I'm supposed to get a vertex from that. Why isn't there just a method that returns an array of `Vector2` objects?

How can I easily render Box2D polygons with ShapeRenderer in LibGDX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Vector2` parameter of `getVertex(Vector2);` is the *output* of the method (I.e. the vertex). I believe you have to supply your own `Vector2` so you can limit garbage (by using pooling or something else).

This means that you should use the supplied `Vector2` as your vertex when drawing. You can then use this `Vector2` and `drawLine();` to draw your shape.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

If what you're looking for is to, for debugging purposes, see the position of all your bodies you can use the `Box2DDebugRenderer` which takes a `World` and a transform matrix and renders a lot of information for you (it will for example show you contacts and the difference between a static and a dynamic body).

```
Box2DDebugRenderer renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
renderer.render(world, camera.combined);
```

If that doesn't fit your purpose you need to iterate over the bodies in the `World` and then for each `Body` get all the `Fixture`s and render their respective `Shape`s. How to do that is slightly different depending on the type of `Shape` but for polygons it might look something like this;

```
void render(Body body, ShapeRenderer renderer) {
  for(Fixture f : body.getFixtureList()) {
    switch(f.getType) {
       case Shape.Type.Polygon: 
       {
         PolygonShape s = (PolygonShape)f.getShape();
         // NOTE: You don't want to be newing this up every time, make sure you keep an array of Vector2s and reuse that!
         Vector2[] vertices = new Vector2[s.getVertexCount()];
         // Build list of transformed vertices
         for(int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); ++i) {
           vertices[i] = new Vector2();
           s.getVertex(i, vertices[i]);
           body.getTransform().mul(vertices[i]);
         }  

         // This assumes a closed polygon, the last vertex is connected with the first.
         for(int i = 0; i < s.getVertexCount(); ++i) {     
           Vector2 a = vertices[i];
           Vector2 b = vertices[(i + 1) % s.getVertexCount()];
           renderer.line(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
         }
       }
       break;
       // And then cover the other types, Circle and Egde here.
    }
  }
}
```